# Checking whether product also exists in a different collection in a Shopify Theme

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, collections, shopify

I have a collection.list.liquid file.

This loops through ALL the products in the store.

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
```

I have created another collection of products that are in a collection cleverly titled 'Special Offers Products', with the url and handle '/special-offers-products'.

Within my FOR loop I want to make an IF statement that simply asks each product within the FOR loop if it is also within this side collection 'Special Offers Products'. If this is TRUE display a little block of code that is essentially a tag that says 'Special Offer!'.

Childishly I have tried (and failed):

```
{% if product.collections contains 'special-offers-products' %}     
    <div class="special-offer-banner">
        Special<br/>
        Offer!
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I am now struggling to think of another way I could run this IF.

Here is my full product FOR loop:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    <div class="single-product">
        <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="box-link"></a>
        <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url({{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }});">
        </div>
        {% if product.collections contains 'special-offers-products' %}     
            <div class="special-offer-banner">
                Special<br/>
                Offer!
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="product-information">
            <p class="product-title">{{ product.title }}</p>
            <p class="product-vendor">{{ product.vendor }}</p>
            <p class="product-price">{{ product.price | money }}</p>
            {% unless product.available %}
                <br><strong>sold out</strong>
            {% endunless %}
            <div class="product-buttons">
                {% include 'view-button' %}
                {% comment %}{% include 'add-to-cart-button' %}{% endcomment %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>no matches</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I to correctly check if the product that is currently being looped over is also placed within another collection?

### Edit

I do not want to know how to create a separate collection of products using the 'Special Offers Products' collection, this needs to be done within the same ALL products collection loop.

Answer (score 4):

You were actually very close.

What's confusing you is that `product.collections` returns the collections object and not the collection handle.

So you can do this instead.

```
{%- assign collection_handles = product.collections | map: 'handle' -%}
{% if collection_handles contains 'special-offers-products' %}     
    <div class="special-offer-banner">
        Special<br/>
        Offer!
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

This should work with your current logic then.

Comment: Firstly- massive thanks for contributing! however, this doesn't appear to work for me. The output for each product that is created in the loop, doesn't use this same url and handle as it is created within the ALL products collection list, so it uses that handle. Not trying to shoot you down, you may be correct and my implementation sucks.

Comment: @JasonIsMyName didn't quite understand your issue here. I'm only getting the collections from the product and creating an array using the map filter, after that I check if the 'special-offers-products' is contained in that array. I don't target the product handle or url or I'm not understanding the issue here. Can you clarify in more detail?

Comment: Of course I will try! I am going to have a look over what I have been working towards, with your code snip in mind. So I can come back to you with something helpful.

Comment: Okay so.. I am going to change my approach as this is realistically (i think) the correct way to do it. Instead of creating a sales collection based upon the products I am adding to this sale collection. I will create a collection that is created based on the compare at price being greater than 0.01. This will then in theory be all the products on sale, correct? I should then technically be able to use the if price is < sale price. run the IF, correct?